# memcpy() changes memory which should not be touched

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcpy

In my code I use array addressing on a heap pointer `int *shifts` to save values into this array. When I use `memcpy()` to copy data between heap areas, the content of the array `shifts[y]` is changed, even I don't see the possibility of a buffer overflow. The problem already happens in the first round of the `for` loop with `s->start` set to `568`.

The code snippet is part of the FFmpeg library.
`av_malloc()` and `av_log()` are wrappers on `malloc()` and `printf()`.

I've tried to output the memory addresses in hope to find out the reason for the problem. Please excuse the bad readability because of the print out code to demonstrate the values after each step.

```
typedef struct LineShiftContext {
    const AVClass *class;
    /* Command line options: */
    int lines, start;
    /* Internal: */
    int nb_planes;
    int planewidth[4];
    int planeheight[4];
    void *filler[4];
    int *shifts;

    void (*recoverlineshifts)(struct LineShiftContext *s, AVFrame *frame);
} LineShiftContext;
////////////////
    for (int p = 0; p < s->nb_planes; p++) {
        s->filler[p] = av_malloc(s->planewidth[p] * (depth <= 8 ? sizeof(uint8_t) : sizeof(uint16_t)));
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "s->planewidth[%d]: %d, s->filler[%d]: %p\n", p, s->planewidth[p], p, s->filler[p]);
    }
    s->shifts = av_malloc(s->planeheight[0]);
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "s->planeheight[0]: %d, s->shifts:   %p\n", s->planeheight[0], s->shifts);
////////////////
static void recoverlineshifts(LineShiftContext *s, AVFrame *frame)
{
    uint8_t *data = frame->data[0];
    int16_t lz = frame->linesize[0];
    int width = s->planewidth[0];
    int height = s->planeheight[0];
    int increment = s->lines >= 0 ? 1 : -1; // if negative, run upwards
    uint8_t *temp = (uint8_t *)s->filler[0];
    int *shifts = s->shifts;
    memset(shifts, 0, height);

    for (int y = s->start, shift_old = 0; y != s->start + s->lines; y += increment) {
        shifts[y] = calculate_shift(s, data + (y - increment) * lz, shift_old, width, data + y * lz);

        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "temp:   %p, line:      %p, lineref: %p, lz: %d, y: %d, yref: %d, shifts: %p, shifts[y]: %d\n",
                temp, data + y * lz, data + (y - increment) * lz, lz, y, y - increment, shifts, shifts[y]);
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "temp++: %p, line++:    %p, width: %d\n",
                temp + FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]), data + y * lz + FFMAX(0, shifts[y]), width - abs(shifts[y]));
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "shifts: %p, y: %d, shifts[y]: %d, -shifts[y]: %d, FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]): %d\n",
                shifts, y, shifts[y], -shifts[y], FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]));
        memcpy(temp + FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]), data + y * lz + FFMAX(0, shifts[y]), width - abs(shifts[y]));
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "shifts: %p, y: %d, shifts[y]: %d, -shifts[y]: %d, FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]): %d\n",
                shifts, y, shifts[y], -shifts[y], FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]));
        ////////////
    }
}
////////////////
    for (int p = 0; p < s->nb_planes; p++)
        av_freep(&s->filler[p]);
    av_freep(&s->shifts);
```

Result:

```
s->planewidth[0]: 704, s->filler[0]: 0x55f36e025940
s->planewidth[1]: 352, s->filler[1]: 0x55f36e025c80
s->planewidth[2]: 352, s->filler[2]: 0x55f36e024a80
s->planeheight[0]: 576, s->shifts:   0x55f36e0251c0
temp:   0x55f36e025940, line:      0x7f8f0e06aa40, lineref: 0x7f8f0e06a780, lz: 704, y: 568, yref: 567, shifts: 0x55f36e0251c0, shifts[y]: -12
temp++: 0x55f36e02594c, line++:    0x7f8f0e06aa40, width: 692
shifts: 0x55f36e0251c0, y: 568, shifts[y]: -12, -shifts[y]: 12, FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]): 12
shifts: 0x55f36e0251c0, y: 568, shifts[y]: 134678279, -shifts[y]: -134678279, FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]): 0
```

Expected (for the last line):

```
shifts: 0x55f36e0251c0, y: 568, shifts[y]: -12, -shifts[y]: 12, FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]): 12
```

Later in the `for` loop I have:

```
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "temp  : %p, lineref:   %p, width: %d\n", temp, data + (y - increment) * lz, FFMAX(0, -shifts[y]));
            memcpy(temp, data + (y - increment) * lz,
                    FFMAX(0, -shifts[y])); // fill left gap from reference line
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "temp++: %p, lineref++: %p, width: %d\n", temp + width - FFMAX(0, shifts[y]), data + (y - increment) * lz + width - FFMAX(0, shifts[y]), FFMAX(0, shifts[y]));
            memcpy(temp + width - FFMAX(0, shifts[y]), data + (y - increment) * lz + width - FFMAX(0, shifts[y]),
                    FFMAX(0, shifts[y])); // fill right gap from reference line
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "line:   %p, temp:      %p, width: %d\n", data + y * lz, temp, width);
            memcpy(data + y * lz, temp, width);
```

where even the pointers run out of scope:

```
temp  : 0x55f36e025940, lineref:   0x7f8f0e06a780, width: 0
temp++: 0x55f365fb54f9, lineref++: 0x7f8f05ffa339, width: 134678279
```

... which finally results in a memory access error.

Comment: `s->filler[p]` if `p` is ever greater than `3` , or the same in `FFMAX(0, -shifts[y])`, you have a problem. I suspect one of those spots is where your problem lies. (aside, you can rest assured that given the proposition that *"memcpy() changes memory which should not be touched"* -- it's not `memcpy` that is at fault...)

Comment: Where is `s->nb_planes` being set?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I only reference to `s->filler[0]` here, so I'm never as high as `3`. And what's the problem about `FFMAX(0, -shifts[y])`? `y` with `568` is within it's size `576`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `s->nb_planes` is set from the FFmpeg program while reading an image file. In my case it is set to `3`, and in my code I only use plane 0.

Comment: I haven't studied your program very hard so I don't know, but make sure you aren't using memcpy for overlapping ranges. If your ranges overlap you need to use memmove instead. memcpy is optimized for high speed and does not do any checking.

Comment: Are you sure that when you're `av_malloc`ing and `memset`ing `shifts` that it shouldn't be `planeheight[0] * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @ZanLynx Yes, I know. That's the reason, why I use the `temp` buffer.
Now you infect me with the idea, that I could use `memmove` instead, thanks!

Comment: @Cornstalks You are right. Very much thanks! That is indeed the reason for the buffer overflow.

Comment: @Cornstalks So you can post this as official answer and earn reputation points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `shifts` is being under-allocated and under-initialized. The definition if `shifts` is:

```
int *shifts;
```

Its allocation and initialization are:

```
s->shifts = av_malloc(s->planeheight[0]);

int height = s->planeheight[0];
int *shifts = s->shifts;
memset(shifts, 0, height);
```

Each of these are missing a multiplication by `sizeof(int)`. It should be:

```
s->shifts = av_malloc(s->planeheight[0] * sizeof(int));

int *shifts = s->shifts;
memset(shifts, 0, height * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Another possibility is: `height * sizeof(*shifts)`. This has the advantage, that no typo is possible and if one changes the type of `shifts` to e.g `*int16_t`, the code remains still correct.